# Listening for sending notifications

Tags: android, database, notifications

Im looking for an android development technique.
Im pretty sure that the things I need are already there,but I`m not sure how to search for it.

What I have so far:
A database on a web server,containing some information and another database with users(android).
A table where every user is connected to some information that needs to be send as a notification to him.

What I need:
The technique that will send the notification right away to every user in my database.

The same thing happens in the Gmail application.
I`m sending a mail and after a few seconds the other part receives a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at Google Cloud Messaging.

Introduction:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Client implementation:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Server Implementation

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html